# how can I run cron job in php project hosting on cpanel

Tags: php, session, cron

I have php project hosting in cpanel.
I specified the cron.php file path in the cpanel cron job and started it once per minute, but the cron.php file starts, but I don't know if there is an error in the code, but the desired operation is not realized.
I used the library in my project as code to handle requests from other common browsers in the cron.php file.
However, other libraries cannot be used.
Why?
What should I do to solve this problem?

However, before using the library functions, they were stored in the log file, but they could not be stored after the library function was called.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$g['to_root'] = '../';
include($g['to_root'] . '_include/core/main_start.php');

$logFile = $g['path']['dir_logs'] . 'cron.txt';

$logActive = false;

if($logActive) {
    file_put_contents($logFile, date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . " START\n", FILE_APPEND);
}

$min = intval(date('i'));
$hour = intval(date('H'));

if ($min == 0) {
    Flashchat::clearHistory();
}

echo 'Cron works';

if($logActive) {
    file_put_contents($logFile, date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . " END\n", FILE_APPEND);
}

include($g['to_root'] . '_include/core/main_close.php');
```